# Running multiple OS on a desktop without a host OS

Tags: vmware, virtualization, operating-systems, bare-metal

Is it possible to run multiple OS a desktop parallely?
I mean without rebooting.
Is it possible by "bare metal virtualization"?

Comment: I mean is it possible use multiple OS parallely on a desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are called [type 1 hypervisors or "native"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification). There are many choices to choose from, just pick any one from the ["Native" section from the bottom of the Wikipeda hypervisors page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#collapseButton0).

Comment: @Ramhound have some humility, and at least read the links first when somebody with an order of magnitude more rep than you answers a question and you think they might not be right.